# Adding logs to a WellSectionWindow

Tags: ocean, petrel

How would one add logs to a well-section window programatically? For the following well-logs within my Petrel input tree and using the code below only "Sonic" log is displayed on the WellSectionWindow

**Well** 
 
->*WellLogs* 
 
    -   Density 
 
    -   Sonic
 
    -   Gamma ray

```
Borehole borehole = arguments.object as Borehole;
WellSectionWindow wsw = WellSectionWindow.CreateWindow();
wsw.ShowObject(borehole);
```

Within Petrel(2013.1), I can navigate to the `Log element->(right-click)->"Add to template"->"Vertical"->"In new track"`. I would like to know if something similar could be achieved using Ocean APIs and guide me towards relevant documentation. Also, I'd like to know why "Sonic" log was displayed within the `WellSectionWindow` in Petrel and how did it get prioritized over Density or Gamma ray log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WellLogVersion of a WellLog corresponds to the global well log in the input tree.
If you want to display the log, you can call wsw.ShowObject(wellLogVersion) and it will be displayed.

If you want to control the order of the logs being displayed, you'll need to deal with the format template nodes of the well section templates. The details can be found in the Ocean dev guide, Volume 9, Chapter 3.

Comment: Your suggestion does work, but is there a way to enable the `Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Well.BoreholeCollection` when adding the global well logs to a WellSectionWindow? `wsw.showObject(WellRoot.Get(Petrel.PrimaryProject)).BoreholeCollection)` doesn't work. I'm having to explicitly check the "Wells folder" node within the Petrel input tree